# Java- database update does not update the database

Tags: java, database, sqlite

```
private static void search(Connection conn) throws SQLException {
    try ( PreparedStatement stat = conn.prepareStatement("select * from town where zip=9999")) {
        ResultSet res = stat.executeQuery();
        while (res.next()) {
            System.out.println(res.getString("zip")+" "+res.getString("name"));
        }
    }
}

private static void bewerk(Connection conn) throws SQLException {
    try ( PreparedStatement stat = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT into town VALUEs (9999,'zzzZZZzzz')")) {
        int res = stat.executeUpdate();
        System.out.println(res);
    }
}



public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        Class.forName(JDBC_DRIVER);

        try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(JDBC_URL)) {
            bewerk(conn);
            search(conn);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.err.println("Database error: " + e);
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        System.err.println("Database driver niet gevonden: " + e);
    }
}
```

Why doesn't ths code update my DB? 
I executed this code, checked it with sqliteBrowser(a program for opening DB's) but I can't find my new value.
(automaticCommit is set on True)

Comment: Show the call to that method in your code. Also, what are you doing with the thrown SQLExceptions?

Comment: Done, added it in question.
I put the sqlexceptions in the method signature , because I don't want to put try-catch-clausules in every single method. I just do it 1 time in the main-method.

Comment: What relevance is the `search()` method? Isn't your problem that the insert does not work?

Comment: So, is it printing anything as a result of the `println(res)`? And are you getting any errors?

Comment: Yes. I use the search method to test if it sees the changes, and it does in my IDE without any errors. However in another program to view the DB  when I refresh the database I can't see any changes.

Comment: Stupid question: Are you commiting?

Comment: I did commit yes. I managed to find the problem. The database actually did update itself, but I was running in a virtual machine which creates a copy of the DB. :) Solved. Thank you for your help.